# Match a regex from characters to end of line but ignore the last character

Tags: regex

The regex

```
(file\..*$)
```

matches "file.xml" correctly in

```
$cd = "..\folder\file.xml"
```

but I'd like to ignore the trailing quote via regex if possible

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say: anything **not a `"`**:

```
(file\.[^"]*)"$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/yZ6hH2/1).

---

In your example, you [**do not even need the anchors**](https://regex101.com/r/yZ6hH2/2):

```
(file\.[^"]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update your regular expression to the following:

```
(file\..*?)"?$
```

That'll make sure that if there is a trailing quote it will not be captured.

Answer (score 0):

Move the last char along with the end marker out of the group:

```
(file\..*).$
```

https://regex101.com/r/bZ7vV5/1

Or if you may have a non-quote last char which you would like to capture instead, then specify this quote explicitly but as optional (`"?`) and make the previous match non-greedy (`.*?`):

```
(file\..*?)"?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/bZ7vV5/3